# Change VS 2010 default skin

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is any one knows how can i change the default (light blue) skin 
of visual studio 2010 ???

Thanks,
Liran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download **Visual Studio Color Theme Editor** from the Extension Manager. (Tools -> Extension Manager)

Comment: You beat me by 30 seconds! :)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to change the Visual Studio 2010 skin is to **[download the Visual Studio Color Theme Editor extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378)**.

You can download the extension from the online gallery (click the link) or you can do it from inside Visual Studio (go to Tools --> Extension Manager --> Online Gallery --> Search for *Visual Studio Color Theme Editor*).

After you install the extension and restart Visual Studio, you should be able to change the skin.